# How to open a popup AND make it flashing FROM the toolbar?

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications

Just AS a chat (yahoomessenger, msn .....) WHEN we get a new message, the corresponding window is flashing

or AS in internet explorer WHEN we finsh downloading something the corresponding window is flashing in the toolbar

How to do it with a popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following javascript to trigger this.

```
window.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not accessible from JavaScript in a web page. You could, however, change the title bar to a string such as "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" and back again for a similar effect.

Example code (live at http://jsbin.com/ifewu3/2):

```
var oldTitle = '', titleBlanked = false, flashInterval;
flashInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if(!titleBlanked) {
        oldTitle = document.title;
        document.title = '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!';
        titleBlanked = true;
    } else {
        document.title = oldTitle;
        titleBlanked = false;
    }
}, 500);
```

Then call `clearInterval(flashInterval)` when you want to stop the flashing.